# Next page token de google API solo retorna 20 resultados

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, scraping, python-requests

Estoy intentando obtener cierta data desde la API de google places, pero cuando ejecuto el código, solo puedo obtener 20 resultados que los repite una y otra vez.

Estuve leyendo que podía ser el "next_page_token", pero no logro solucionarlo. Dejo el código que estoy utilizando:

```
import json
import csv
import requests
import time



url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.45326376,-70.65663569&radius=50000&type=pharmacy&key=MY_API_KEY'

headers={'content-type':'application/json',
         'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0'}


def csv_write():
    csvfile =open('farmacias.csv','w')
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(["name","rating","lat","long"])

    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
    for obj in response['results']:
        writer.writerow ([obj['name'],obj['rating'],obj['geometry']['location']['lat'],obj['geometry']['location']['lng']])

    print ('next_page_token' in response)
    while 'next_page_token' in response:
        URL = url + '&pagetoken=' + response['next_page_token']
        time.sleep(5)
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
        for obj in response['results']:
            writer.writerow ([obj['name'],obj['rating'],obj['geometry']['location']['lat'],obj['geometry']['location']['lng']])

    else:
        print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_write()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando llamas por segunda vez a la función `request()` utilizas la variable `url` que es la definida al principio del todo en el código, cuando debes de usar la variable `URL` que es a la que asignas la paginación.

**Te recomiendo que llames a las variables de forma distinta**, ya que aunque Python es Case Sensitive (distinge entre minúsculas y mayúsculas, por lo que "url" es distinto de "URL"). Puede ser lioso a la hora de programar

Aquí te dejo el código, yo le he cambiado el nombre a **URL** por **pagination**

```
import json
import csv
import requests
import time


#Está era la variable que estabas usando en el "while", por eso siempre se repetía
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.45326376,-70.65663569&radius=50000&type=pharmacy&key=MY_API_KEY'

headers={'content-type':'application/json',
         'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0'}


def csv_write():
    csvfile =open('farmacias.csv','w')
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(["name","rating","lat","long"])

    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
    for obj in response['results']:
        writer.writerow ([obj['name'],obj['rating'],obj['geometry']['location']['lat'],obj['geometry']['location']['lng']])

    print ('next_page_token' in response)
    while 'next_page_token' in response:
        
        #Aunque el nombre vale, lo cambiamos para evitar confusiones
        pagination = url + '&pagetoken=' + response['next_page_token']
        time.sleep(5)

        #Aquí estaba el fallo usamos "pagination" en vez de "url"
        response = requests.get(url=pagination, headers=headers).json()
        for obj in response['results']:
            writer.writerow ([obj['name'],obj['rating'],obj['geometry']['location']['lat'],obj['geometry']['location']['lng']])

    else:
        print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_write()
```

Comment: Muuuuuuuuchas gracias! ayer estuve todo el día intentando solucionar el problema y era eso.